# How to tell start-stop-daemon to update $HOME and $USER accordingly to --chuid parameter

Tags: linux, users, environment-variables, home-directory

I'm trying to run a service that uses **$HOME** and **$USER** environment variables. I could set them in service itself, but that would only be a temporary solution.

Let's say I have a script `test.sh` with following content:

```
echo $USER
```

And I run it with `start-stop-daemon` to see my results:

```
$ start-stop-daemon --start --exec `pwd`/test.sh --user guest --group guest --chuid -guest
root
```

Seems like it does not update environment, maybe that should be reported as a bug?

I have found a nasty hacky solution, which only works (for unknown reason) on my this simple use case:

```
$ start-stop-daemon --exec /usr/bin/sudo --start -- -u guest -i 'echo $USER'
guest
```

I'm sure someone else stumbled upon this, I'm interested in clean solution.

```
$ start-stop-daemon --version
start-stop-daemon 1.13.11+gentoo
```

Comment: It's clearly changing the UID. If you add `mktemp` to the script, the file it creates `/tmp/tmp.*` is owned by guest. Mysterious. And I get "root" as output, too. I tried various combinations of switches `-i` and `-l` in the shebang: `#!/bin/bash -il` and that didn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be the intended behavior. The manual page shows an `--env` option for `start-stop-daemon`:

```
   -e|--env env-name
          Set an environment variable whose name  and  value  is  env-name
          before   starting  executable.   Example:  -e  HOME="/home/user"
          exports an environment variable whose name is  HOME  with  value
          "/home/user".   Note,  only  one  --env  option is suppoted, use
          /usr/bin/env if you need more.
```

The author used `$HOME` in the example, which I take to mean that it wouldn't normally set it. I don't see any other options for updating the environment of the process you're starting.

Try running `start-stop-daemon` like this:

```
USER=guest HOME=~guest start-stop-daemon --start --exec /path/to/prog ...
```

Another alternative would be to run the script under `sudo`:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --exec /usr/bin/sudo -- -H -u guest /path/to/prog
```

`sudo` will automatically set `$USER`, and the `-H` option tells it to set `$HOME` as well. I ran both of these with my own `test.sh` that prints the value of thse variables, and both updated them as desired. I'm partial to the first because it doens't add another program to the mix, but that's just me.

Comment: +1 - $HOME and $USER are typically set by `login`, not by the shell. So you have to use something like this to make it work as the OP wants. The $USER and $HOME variables that the OP is seeing are most likely being inherited from the shell in which he is running start-stop-dameon.

Comment: Thanks, James. I thought that was the case, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: yeah, sudo seems to know better about environments. I can not get hudson runing with this method, but I guess that's the way. I'll come back when I get hudson daemon working. Cheers James!

Comment: The Hudson documentation has a suggestion on running it as a daemon here: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Installing+Hudson+as+a+Unix+daemon

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the shell is different for the script than for the environment in which `start-stop-daemon` is running. Try specifying the shell in your script using a shebang line:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

On my system, `sh` is Dash which doesn't set `$USER` but will inherit it from a parent's environment.

Comment: Even setting the shebang, root is still printed.